# ExoPlayer - play 10 files one after another

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I have 10 video i need to play, once one is done, the next one starts to play.

I'm using [Google's ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), I use the example in the [DEMO @ GitHub](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo).
I can play 1 video but if i try to play the next one, it wont start.

If i try to reInit the player, and the start playing again, it crashes.

```
private void loadvideo() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_LIBRARY_URL + currentVideo + ".mp4");
    sampleSource = new FrameworkSampleSource(this, uri, null, 2);

    // 1. Instantiate the player.
    // 2. Construct renderers.
    videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
    audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
    // 3. Inject the renderers through prepare.
    player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
    // 4. Pass the surface to the video renderer.
    surface = surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface();

    player.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface);
    // 5. Start playback.
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged + " + playbackState);
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                currentVideo++;
                loadNextVideo();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }
    });

}
```

What am i doing wrong?
How can i play videos continuity?

Thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting in crash?

Comment: also, what's your loadNextVideo() code look like.

Answer (score 16):

You can reuse the ExoPlayer up  until the point that you call release(), and then it should no longer be used.

To change the media that it is currently playing, you essentially need to perform the following steps:

```
// ...enable autoplay...
player.stop();
player.seekTo(0L);
player.prepare(renderers);
```

Creating the renderers is a little bit more involved, but that's the flow you should follow and the player should be able to play back to back videos.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this solution worked for me

Comment: It was not obvious to me at all that you had to seek to 0 before preparing the renderer again. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Exoplayer change mp4 video success. I use the example in the DEMO.
1.DEMO project in DemoPlayer.java:

```
 private final RendererBuilder rendererBuilder;
 //remove final,then modify that:

 private RendererBuilder rendererBuilder;

 //and add the set method:
 public void setRendererBuilder(RendererBuilder rendererBuilder){
      this.rendererBuilder = rendererBuilder;
  }

 //finally,add stop method
 public void stop(){
      player.stop();
  }
```

2.DEMO project in PlayerActivity.java:
  add method:

```
private void changeVideo(){
        player.stop();
        player.seekTo(0L);
        //you must change your contentUri before invoke getRendererBuilder();
        player.setRendererBuilder(getRendererBuilder());
        player.prepare();
        playerNeedsPrepare = false;
    }
```

remember change param contentUri before invoke changeVideo method.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ConcatenatingMediaSource` to play files in sequence.
For example, for playing 2 media Uris (`firstVideoUri` and `secondVideoUri`), use this code:

```
MediaSource firstSource =
    new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(firstVideoUri);
MediaSource secondSource =
    new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(secondVideoUri);

ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource =
    new ConcatenatingMediaSource(firstSourceTwice, secondSource);
```

And then use `concatenatedSource` to play media files sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Answering my own question.
on the example, google init the ExoPlayer at OnResume().
i had to re-init for every video like that:

```
player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(2, 1000, 5000);
```

if someone has a better idea, please let me know.

Comment: This does not fix the problem for me :(

Comment: @Marky17 Before  instantiating a new instance call releasePlayer() method.

Comment: @Shahar Hi I am trying to create a simple video player program using ExoPlayer but yet not done, I have checked your Github repositories but did not find your ExoPlayer sample there... please post your sample and share link with me.. so I will learn by that one..

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, you could refer to ConcatenatingMediaSource to achieve auto play next media.

In Demo App example :
1. Launch ExoPlayer
2. Select Playlists
3. Choose Cats->Dogs